# multiselect is reset whenever the popover closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover, bootstrap-multiselect

I have some multiselects inside a popover, but whenever the popover closes, the multiselect is deleted, is there a way to put a multiselect inside a popover without it losing the selected data?

in the code I create the multiselect when I click the button, I believe this may be the cause of the problem, but I couldn't find another way to add multiselect to the popover. I followed one of the answers to this question:

[https//stackoverflow.com/questions/ 22409391/how-to-put-a-multiselect-in-a-popover](https://%20in%20the%20code%20I%20create%20the%20multiselect%20when%20I%20click%20the%20button,%20I%20believe%20this%20may%20be%20the%20cause%20of%20the%20problem,%20but%20I%20couldn%27t%20find%20another%20way%20to%20add%20multiselect%20to%20the%20popover,%20I%20followed%20one%20of%20the%20answers%20to%20this%20question:%20https:%20//stackoverflow.com/questions%20/%2022409391%20/%20how-to-put-a-multiselect-in-a-popover)

that is my code:

```js
 let popover_filters = '<div id="popover_filters" class="text-center">'+
                          '<select id="activity_filter_sector" class="form-control" name="multiselect[]" multiple="multiple" alt="setor" required>'+
                            '<option value="0">Contábil e Financeiro</option>'+
                            '<option value="1">Fiscal e Tributário</option>'+
                            '<option value="2">Pessoal e Trabalhista</option>'+
                            '<option value="3">Gestão e controladoria</option>'+
                          '</select>'+
                          '<select id="activity_filter_company" class="form-control" name="multiselect[]" multiple="multiple" alt="empresa" required>'+
                            '<option value="0">Contábil e Financeiro</option>'+
                            '<option value="1">Fiscal e Tributário</option>'+
                            '<option value="2">Pessoal e Trabalhista </option>'+
                            '<option value="3">Gestão e controladoria Gestão e controladoria Gestão e controladoria</option>'+
                          '</select>'+
                          '<select id="activity_filter_status" class="form-control" name="multiselect[]" multiple="multiple" alt="status" required>'+
                            '<option value="0">agendado</option>'+
                            '<option value="1">concluído</option>'+
                            '<option value="2">pendente</option>'+
                            '<option value="3">em atraso</option>'+
                          '</select>'+
                          '<select id="activity_filter_users" class="form-control" name="multiselect[]" multiple="multiple" alt="usuários" required>'+
                            '<option value="0">Contábil e Financeiro</option>'+
                            '<option value="1">Fiscal e Tributário</option>'+
                            '<option value="2">Pessoal e Trabalhista</option>'+
                            '<option value="3">Gestão e controladoria</option>'+
                          '</select>'+
                        '</div>'

                        
  $('#activity_filter_btn').popover({
     html:true,  placement : 'bottom', content: popover_filters, trigger:'click', 
    }).on('click',function () {
      $('#activity_filter_sector').multiselect()
      $('#activity_filter_company').multiselect()
      $('#activity_filter_status').multiselect()
      $('#activity_filter_users').multiselect()
    }).on("hide.bs.popover", function(){
      let total = 0
      total += $('#activity_filter_sector').val().length
      total += $('#activity_filter_company').val().length
      total += $('#activity_filter_status').val().length
      total += $('#activity_filter_users').val().length
      if (total >0){
        $(this).addClass('btn-primary')
        $(this).removeClass('btn-default')
      }else{
        $(this).addClass('btn-default')
        $(this).removeClass('btn-primary')
      }
    });
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <!-- multiselect -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" integrity="sha512-EvvoSMXERW4Pe9LjDN9XDzHd66p8Z49gcrB7LCUplh0GcEHiV816gXGwIhir6PJiwl0ew8GFM2QaIg2TW02B9A==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js" integrity="sha512-aFvi2oPv3NjnjQv1Y/hmKD7RNMendo4CZ2DwQqMWzoURKxcqAoktj0nNG4LU8m23+Ws9X5uVDD4OXLqpUVXD5Q==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      
<button id="activity_filter_btn"class="mt-3 btn btn btn-default"><i class="fas fa-filter mr-2"></i>Filtrar</button>
```

Comment: I think your hunch is correct, it's resetting because the element is destroyed and recreated each time the popover is closed, effectively setting all multiselects back to default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about solving this is by storing your selected values somewhere that persists between popover open/ close.

On open, set the select values using `.multiselect('select', [value_arr])`.

On close, store the values, so that they'll be accessible next time the popover is opened.

I just used 4 variables here, but you could conceivably use any storage mechanism that's convenient to your project.

```js
let popover_filters = '<div id="popover_filters" class="text-center">' +
  '<select id="activity_filter_sector" class="form-control" name="multiselect[]" multiple="multiple" alt="setor" required>' +
  '<option value="0">Contábil e Financeiro</option>' +
  '<option value="1">Fiscal e Tributário</option>' +
  '<option value="2">Pessoal e Trabalhista</option>' +
  '<option value="3">Gestão e controladoria</option>' +
  '</select>' +
  '<select id="activity_filter_company" class="form-control" name="multiselect[]" multiple="multiple" alt="empresa" required>' +
  '<option value="0">Contábil e Financeiro</option>' +
  '<option value="1">Fiscal e Tributário</option>' +
  '<option value="2">Pessoal e Trabalhista </option>' +
  '<option value="3">Gestão e controladoria Gestão e controladoria Gestão e controladoria</option>' +
  '</select>' +
  '<select id="activity_filter_status" class="form-control" name="multiselect[]" multiple="multiple" alt="status" required>' +
  '<option value="0">agendado</option>' +
  '<option value="1">concluído</option>' +
  '<option value="2">pendente</option>' +
  '<option value="3">em atraso</option>' +
  '</select>' +
  '<select id="activity_filter_users" class="form-control" name="multiselect[]" multiple="multiple" alt="usuários" required>' +
  '<option value="0">Contábil e Financeiro</option>' +
  '<option value="1">Fiscal e Tributário</option>' +
  '<option value="2">Pessoal e Trabalhista</option>' +
  '<option value="3">Gestão e controladoria</option>' +
  '</select>' +
  '</div>';

//Initialize storage vars:
let sector = [];
let company = [];
let status = [];
let users = [];


$('#activity_filter_btn').popover({
  html: true,
  placement: 'bottom',
  content: popover_filters,
  trigger: 'click',
}).on('click', function() {
//On open, set selects to the stored values
  $('#activity_filter_sector').multiselect('select', sector)
  $('#activity_filter_company').multiselect('select', company)
  $('#activity_filter_status').multiselect('select', status)
  $('#activity_filter_users').multiselect('select', users)
}).on("hide.bs.popover", function() {
//On close, store the values
  sector = $('#activity_filter_sector').val()
  company = $('#activity_filter_company').val()
  status = $('#activity_filter_status').val()
  users = $('#activity_filter_users').val()

  let total = 0
  total += sector.length
  total += company.length
  total += status.length
  total += users.length
  if (total > 0) {
    $(this).addClass('btn-primary')
    $(this).removeClass('btn-default')
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('btn-default')
    $(this).removeClass('btn-primary')
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- multiselect -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" integrity="sha512-EvvoSMXERW4Pe9LjDN9XDzHd66p8Z49gcrB7LCUplh0GcEHiV816gXGwIhir6PJiwl0ew8GFM2QaIg2TW02B9A==" crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js" integrity="sha512-aFvi2oPv3NjnjQv1Y/hmKD7RNMendo4CZ2DwQqMWzoURKxcqAoktj0nNG4LU8m23+Ws9X5uVDD4OXLqpUVXD5Q==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="activity_filter_btn" class="mt-3 btn btn btn-default"><i class="fas fa-filter mr-2"></i>Filtrar</button>
```